# Azure Biztalk Services time out issue when processing a large CSV file

Tags: biztalk

I have a simple azure biztalk services project.

It has a FTP source that reads a .CSV file and writes to an on-premise sqlserver database table.

I successfully deployed and it works for small .CSV files (around 800 rows) quite well.  But, when I have a large file (around 6500 rows.  Actually, this is also very samll file in my opinion), it fails with the following error.  Below this error, you will see my configurations for the SQLServer Adapter Service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<s:Fault xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Code>
    <s:Value>s:Receiver</s:Value>
    <s:Subcode>
      <s:Value>s:SendError</s:Value>
    </s:Subcode>
  </s:Code>
  <s:Reason>
    <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The operation with action "TableOp/Insert/dbo/tblVMSData"  
               took longer than the specified timeout "00:01:00".</s:Text>
  </s:Reason>
</s:Fault>

My on premise SQL Server adapter service has the following configuration.

<basicHttpRelayBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpRelayBinding1" 
                 closeTimeout="00:20:00"
                 openTimeout="00:20:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:20:00"
                 maxBufferPoolSize=" 1048576" 
                 maxBufferSize="67108864"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="67108864"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpRelayBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to make the timeout value on the server side larger too!  So if you have a look in your BizTalk Services project, look for your SQL endpoint configuration file (under you itinerary in solution explorer) and edit the WCF configuration values there too.
Does that work ?

Comment: If you look at my post, I already copied the basicHttpRelayBinding settings for the SQL endpoint.  There are 4 timeout values, OpenTimeout, receiveTimeout, Closetimeout and sendtimeout.  I bumped them to 20 min.  But, it didn't solve the problem.  Are you referring to something else?Have you successfully deployed a Biztalk Services project with SQL Adapter Service end point that works with large number of rows in a flat file?  Please let me know.

Comment: Hello.  You have to configure the endpoint both on Services (bridge!) and on Client (adapter service) side.  Did you configure both?
Btw: i haven't done any large file tests with SQL yet.

Comment: I'm new to Biztalk services.  Could you please be more specific about the configuration options like the name of the option and the file name  and where to find it?  I already configured the WCF and WF Services for the SQL Data Adapter data services under Biztalk Adapter Service in IIS.  I changed the unload instance when idel timeout and persist instances when idle.  I bumped both of them to 20 min.  But, they didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the configuration options for the timeout.  They are not in any config file.  They are not even in the biztalk services project.

You have to right click your SQL Target, under LOB Types under Biztalk Adapter Services, and select the properties.  In the properties, Click on the Binding Configuration.  It opens up Advanced Adapter Configuration.  There are four timeouts "Open Timeout", "Receive Timeout", "Send Timeout" and "Close Timeout".

What is strange is that these timeouts also appear in the config file that is automatically generated when you drag and drop the SQL Target on to your MessageFlowItinerary.  But, changing them in the config file seems to be not enough in my case.

Also, when you open IIS Management console, there you can change client configuration for timeouts by clicking on the Configure option under "Manage WCF and WF Services".  If you do not see "Manage WCF and WF Services", you haven't installed the Windows Server App Fabric SDK.  Download and install it.

Microsoft should really make it easy to find and change configuration for both server and client from a single simple page.  It is really frustrating to click through different things to find the options.  It should simply work out of the box.  On one hand they give flexibility by providing configuration option and with the other hand they rob it by hiding the configuration options under different rocks.